# Oracle BI - publisher error "unable to extend table APPLSYS.FND_CONC_PP_ACTIONS"

Tags: oracle11g, bi-publisher

We're geting this error when we remote-login into the BI publisher server. is there anything we can do about it?

[image]

[I read through a website that describes it](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?36199-ORA-01653-unable-to-extend-table), but not sure how to go about this. Does the fact that we VPN into it affect things(i.e maybe we can't change tablespace/memory )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tablespace APPS_TS_TX_DATA in you EBS database has no space left for allocation. Nothing specific to BIP, same issue may be encountered in case of any concurrent request submission.

Contact DBA support.